# Is it possible to store custom runner output to pillar data in SALTSTACK?

Tags: saltstack

I have a Salt formula that runs on my minions, and it runs a custom module that reaches out to the web for some JSON data for the latest version of chrome. It works great, but I thought it would be better to run it as a runner on the master and store it as pillar data for the minions to access. That way I don't have hundreds of minions querying the web unnecessarily vs just once on the master.

I'm not finding anything helpful online. Is it even possible?

```
def latest():

    import json
    import urllib.request

    url = 'https://omahaproxy.appspot.com/all.json'
    resp = urllib.request.urlopen(url)

    data = json.loads(resp.read())

    for each in data:
        if each.get("os") == "win":
            versions = each.get("versions")
            for version in versions:
                if version.get("channel") == "stable":
                    latest = (version.get("current_version"))
    return latest
```

I can run it as is in /etc/salt/_modules, as well as a runner in /etc/salt/_runners on the master.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious way is to make it a [custom pillar](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/topics/development/modules/external_pillars.html) instead. However, that just means the master runs it once for every minion, instead of the minions running it themselves.

To have your runner put the result somewhere all your minions can get it, you could do this, for example, assuming the default pillar root configuration:

```python
__salt__["file.write"]("/srv/pillar/omahaproxy.sls", 
                       "omahaproxy.latest: " + latest)
```